# How to get role permission or scope for grant_type client_credential in wso2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have created a service provider in wso2 IS.Under `'Role/Permission Configuration' section` of that service provider we have added some custom permission.
Is there any way for the `'oauth2/token'` call to return the permission associated with that service provider. currently we are passing the scope as `'openid'` and getting id_token in response we also want id_token along with permission values. 
or is there any way to create scope for each service_provider and get in 'oauth2/token' response?
**Note: We are using grant_type='client_credentials' for getting id_token.**

Answer (score 1):

**Note:-** With client credentials grant type we don't have any user authentication, only the client will be validated using client id & secret. Therefore there is no way to get service provider vise permission along with id token. The below solution would be useful when you use a grant type where user authentication exists.

Writing a custom claim handler and handle the logic to assign permission values in that custom claim handler. I have written a sample custom claim handler to retrieve custom permissions along with id token.You could refer https://github.com/nilasini/CustomPermissionClaimHandler and follow the readme instructions.